# Laravel dompdf save to file

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am using this pdf plugin for Laravel [dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). And when I want to save it to file I use

```
return PDF::loadView('pdf.offer', array('request' => $userRequest, 'price' => $request->price))->save(public_path().config('app.offer_files').$request_id.'/'.$offer->file)->stream();
```

**But it shows an error**

> file_put_content('....') file does not exist

So when I generated file witch name **file.pdf** and tried to save it to this file it worked. So if the file exists before I try to save it everything is fine. So how can I dynamically create this file with the appropriate name so I can save it?

Comment: is the target directory already exist before you try to save it? May be your should create the target directory first. Then save it.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra I've tried it doesn't work. I tried creating and empty file and it works. but I am generating the name dynamically so I need to create a file dynamically